# Google Chrome extension and closing popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closing popup window created by Google Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950981/closing-popup-window-created-by-google-chrome-extension)

I've just started to play with Google Chrome extensions and tried to create some extensions from bookmarklets. I tried [official Delicious bookmarklet](http://www.delicious.com/help/bookmarklets) and everythying works fine except popup that it creates doesn't close on link submit when you use similar code in extension.

Here is the code for extension:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab){
    f='http://www.delicious.com/save?url='+tab.url+'&title='+tab.title+'&v=6&';a=function(){if(!window.open(f+'noui=1&jump=doclose','deliciousuiv6','location=yes,links=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,width=550,height=550'))location.href=f+'jump=yes'};if(/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent)){setTimeout(a,0)}else{a()}
  });
});
```

Is there some other method I should use if I want to close popup on link submit?

Comment: Never mind, found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950981/closing-popup-window-created-by-google-chrome-extension Guess I should do a better search next time…

Comment: I guess you know that Yahoo are closing down delicious.

Comment: @Julian: Delicious has been acquired, not shut down: http://blog.delicious.com/blog/2011/05/youtube-founders-acquire-delicious.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924615/chrome-extension-force-popup-html-to-close