# Chrome extension: force popup.html to close

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm wondering is there anyway I can force popup.html to close?

Comment: Do you want to close it while your in the popup or some other page closing it?

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Within a popup javascript:

```
window.close();
```

Comment: how can I close popup from background?

Comment: @MahbubulHaque Have the foreground bind an event listener to the background page. The background page triggers the event and the foreground responds by closing itself.

Comment: @SeanAnderson - could you point me to some code that illustrates this?