# what is the use of window.open('','_self').close(); in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

1. When I click the extension icon, a popup is shown.
2. After that, when I try to click "URL restrictions", it will open a window, after that when I click the popup again, the popup is overlapping that url restriction window.
3. The above issue happens on Windows only, not on Linux.

So I have added `window.open('','_self').close();` which apparently fixed the issue. But not exactly. Is it correct? I have referred this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950981/closing-popup-window-created-by-google-chrome-extension) but can not understand the meaning.

What is the purpose of `window.open('','_self').close();`?
**EDIT:** this is my popup.js

```
  function click(e) {


    var windowObj = window.open(site_exception_url, 'url_window', params);     
    windowObj.focus();
    window.close();
    window.open('','_self').close();
    return false;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows the popup isn't closed automatically after a new window is opened from a link within the popup.

Close it in the click handler manually, this won't hurt Linux but will help on Windows:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.localName == "a") {
        close();
    }
});
```

The related questions linked in your question don't apply here as the first is for userscripts, not extensions, and the second isn't for popups shown by the browser when you click the toolbar button.

Comment: what is meant by `a` here?

Comment: what should i use?here

Comment: ` <div id="gu_widget">Show gUnify Panel</div>
     <div id="gu_google_sync">Sync Contacts</div>
    <div id="gu_call_report">Reports</div>
    <div id="gu_site_exception">URL Restrictions</div>
    <div id="help_feedback">Help & Feedback</div>
    <div id="gu_logout">Logout</div>`

Comment: Use `div` instead of `a`

Comment: ji still need to clarify,kindly help me tomorrow

Comment: i accpet ur answer,but the popup sometime get overlapping the url restriction window:( but sometime working fine....May i know the reason?

Comment: Use `if (event.target.id.indexOf("gu_") == 0) {`

Comment: Actually what does it means?

Comment: Apparently there are other problems in your code which contributed to the conflict.

Comment: For example you already have the code which closes the popup after the new window is created. Try to close first. Or use chrome.windows.create to open the new window. There are many things to try.

Comment: And there's no need for `window.open('','_self').close();`

Comment: ya i too think the same,ok let me check