# Can an extension close it's own popup opened by a browserAction or pageAction?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

I know there is the [`openPopup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/openPopup) API to open a browserAction popup.

However, when it is open and a user e.g. selected something, can I somehow close it?

The same applies for a pageAction.

---

Cross-posted [at Mozilla Discourse](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/can-an-extension-close-its-own-popup-opened-by-a-browseraction-or-pageaction/38645?u=rugkx).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closing popup window created by Google Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950981/closing-popup-window-created-by-google-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, as for any other website a simple `window.close();` works totally fine!

This was too simple.

Only tested in Firefox though.

**Edit:** [As @juraj.masiar made me aware](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/can-an-extension-close-its-own-popup-opened-by-a-browseraction-or-pageaction/38645/3?u=rugkx) this won't work for Firefox for Android though:

> You will have to use `browser.tabs.getCurrent().then(tab => browser.tabs.remove(tab.id))`. Plus you need to detect that you are running Android using `browser.runtime.getPlatformInfo()` function.

Comment: It does work just as well in Chrome. If you call it from a popup, it closes.